# Can I create an email for the user based on input for the first and last name using postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, calculated-columns, create-table

I am pretty new to Postgres, and I am making a mock database that manages students for a university so I can get a better understanding of how Postgres works.

I am creating a student table that has columns for student id, enrollment date, grad year, first/last name, and a university email address. At the moment I just have the email column set to NOT NULL and the user has to enter their own email address, but clearly this is not how email addresses at a university work.

I was wondering if there was a way to make the email be created dynamically based off of what the user inputs as their first and last name. For example, if I were to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('bob', 'smith');
```

An email address would be created on the fly for bob smith in the format 'bobsmith@university.com', so my table would look like:

```
 student_id | enrollment_date | grad_year |             email              | student_first | student_last 
------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------------------+---------------+--------------
          2 | 2020-12-28      |    2024   |     bobsmith@university.com    |      bob      | smith
```

Is there a way that I can create a function that takes the values from the student_first and student_last columns and create an email based on them?

Any links to readable documentation would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways to accomplish what you want: a function/procedure or a (I hate to say) a Trugger. However, generated column will not work in this case: What happens when a second student "Bob Smith" registers. You can use a function to generate the email address - with a number, if needed, to make it unique.

```
create or replace 
function generate_email_address(first_name_in text
                               ,last_name_in  text
                               )
  returns text 
  language sql 
as $$
   with email(num) as 
        ( select count(*) 
            from students 
           where lower(first_name) = lower(first_name_in) 
             and lower(last_name)  = lower(last_name_in) 
        ) 
   select lower(first_name_in) ||
          lower(last_name_in)  || 
          case when num = 0 then '' else to_char(num+1,'FM99') end ||
          '@university.com'
     from email; 
$$;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25fc6123dccdf74fcc7774a90455d1b5):

Comment: Do you know if there’s a way I can only add numbers if there’s a duplicate, and not on the first entry?

Comment: Check the Example from above answer. That is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1):

> An email address would be created on the fly for bob smith in the format 'bobsmith@university.com'

You can use a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```
create table students (
    student_id serial primary key,
    first_name text not null,
    last_name text not null,
    ...
    email text 
        generated always as (first_name || '.' || last_name || '@university.com') 
        stored
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72edd3c91931c3fee4b51fef87f7ae02)**:

```
INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('bob', 'smith');
-- 1 rows affected

SELECT * FROM students;

student_id | first_name | last_name | email                   
---------: | :--------- | :-------- | :-----------------------
         1 | bob        | smith     | bob.smith@university.com
```